# Accessing an object with a variable that is a string. Javascript

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

This is the code for a bot for discord I'm trying to create:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require("./config.json");
const bot = new Discord.Client();

var prefix = '!';
var allqueues = [];

function queue(game,pplneeded,tag){
    this.game = game;
    this.pplneeded = pplneeded;
    this.ppljoined = 1;    
    this.tag = tag;
    allqueues.push(tag);
}
bot.on('message',(message) => {
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix+'prefix')){
        var member = message.mentions.members.first();

        prefix=(message.content).split(" ")[1];
        message.channel.send('The command prefix has been set to '+(message.content).split(/\s+/g)[1] + ' .');
}
if(message.content == (prefix+'rules')){
    message.channel.send('I\'ll keep these rules short and sweet, \'cuz this is just a casual gaming server. \n No spamming. Alright, that\'s it.');
}
if(message.content == (prefix+'help')){
    message.channel.send('Simply type **' + prefix + 'q** ***game people_needed tag*** to create a queue, and **' + prefix + 'j** ***tag*** to join a queue.');
    message.channel.send('Type **' + prefix + 'eq** ***tag*** to exit a queue, and **' + prefix + 'd** ***tag*** to dismantle a queue.');
    message.channel.send('Type **' + prefix + 'inf** ***tag*** to find info about a queue.');
}
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix+'q')){
    var a = message.content.split(/\s+/g);
    a[3] = new queue(a[1],a[2],a[3]);
    message.channel.send(a[1]+' '+a[2]+' '+a[3].tag);
    message.channel.send('A new queue was made! Type **' + prefix + 'j ' + a[3].tag + '** to join this '+a[1]+' queue!')
    message.channel.send(allqueues);
}
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix+'j')){
    var b = message.content.split(/\s+/g);
    if (b[2]=undefined){
        message.channel.send('That\'s not a valid tag!') 
        return;
    }else{
        b[2].ppljoined=b[2].ppljoined+1;
        message.channel.send(message.author + ' has joined the ' + b[2] + 'queue!~~');
        if (b[2].ppljoined==b[2].pplneeded){
            message.channel.send(b[2] + ' has all the needed people!');
            index = allqueues.indexOf(b[2])
            allqueues.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

}
});

bot.login(config.token);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to access one of the objects with the "b" array. As you can see, I tried using `b[3]`, but that was to no avail. Please help. If it may shed some light, here is the error text when I type `!q game 5 tagyoureit` then `!j tagyoureit` in a discord server where the bot is:

```
C:\Users\----\Desktop\gamebot\index.js:42
        b[2].ppljoined=b[2].ppljoined+1;
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'ppljoined' of undefined
    at Client.bot.on (C:\Users\----\Desktop\gamebot\index.js:42:32)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Client.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\----\Desktop\gamebot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\M
essageCre
ate.js:9:34)
at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\----\Desktop\gamebot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketP
acketMa
nager.js:102:65)
at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\----\Desktop\gamebot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:325
:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\--\Desktop\gamebot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnectio
n.js:28
8:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\----
\Desktop\gamebot\node_modules\ws\lib\EventTarget.js:103:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:213:7)
```

Comment: Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Javascript are zero-indexed, meaning that the first element in the array is at index `0`, the second `1`, and so on. Since you are looking for the second element in the `b` array, you want `b[1]` rather than `b[2]`

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that for the second part. However, there is still an issue: `Cannot read property 'ppljoined' of undefined`. How do you read it then?

Comment: Well, if no key is provided, you want to check if `b[1] == undefined` not `b[1] = undefined`. Also, there is another problem that every time `message.content.split` is called, it creates a *new* object. You probably want to store a global object that holds keys to each tag. That way, you won't lose the value of `ppljoined` each time `bot.on` is called

Comment: The global object that holds the tags are in `allqueues`, which is an array that holds all the objects.

Answer (score 0):

How many elements are in the `b` array? Try to `console.log(b)` after you split the `message.content` to make sure.

Also, the code should have gone into the if statement if `b[2]` is undefined, but you have a typo in the `if (b[2]=undefined){` statement (only one equal sign). Try to change it to `if (b[2] == undefined){` or just `if (b[2]){`

Comment: There are two items in `b`, but now I have changed all the `b[2]`'s into `b[1]`'s, as that will access the second element. Even when I have fixed these, when I try to read `b[1].pplneeded`, I get `undefined`, as is when I try to read `b[1].ppljoined`.

Comment: Could you show the output of the `console.log(b)` and update the code you posted with your current code?

Comment: It's fine. I tinkered some more, and I'm testing a possible solution now: making a global object `var tags:{}` then when I want to add to it I just set it like `tags[(tagname)]={object stuff}`. I'm not sure if it'll work though.

Answer (score 0):

`b[2] = undefined` is an assignment, not an expression. Change this to `b[2] === undefined` (or `!!B[2]`)